# Why is a pointer used when using arguments?

Tags: c

Had a question about this `*argv[]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *input = argv[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (isalpha(input[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
```

`argc` makes sense to me as it is a int variable that contains the number of arguments passed with the command. However why would `argv[]` need to be a pointer instead of also a variable in and of itself?

Where is the memory provisioned for the arguments, is there a limit? Are there potential 'catches' to using arguments for input instead of fgets?

Comment: It is an array of pointers to char, pointers to char are the std c way of representing strings.

Comment: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=+char+*argv%5B%5D

Comment: When there's a need to store and pass around an array of strings of unpredictable (variable) length, a "jagged array" approach works pretty well. Jagged array is implemented through an array of pointers. This is exactly what you see in this case.

Comment: Oh, so if the arguments were actually sing chars or ints then it would not be necessary?

Comment: A pointer is a variable

Comment: the main() function seems to be missing a few trailing lines, Could you correct your question, or clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv` is a pointer to the first element of an array of `char*`. C doesn't actually have the ability to pass arrays as arguments, it passes a pointer to the first element of the array instead.

As for the memory, typically, the arguments are actually stored as a single contiguous block of memory with `NUL`s separating the strings. `argv` references an array that points to the beginning of each argument, but the pointers aren't independently allocated. If you call a program with:

```
foo arg1 arg2 arg3
```

the actual layout in memory would often be something like this:

```
"foo\0arg1\0arg2\0arg3\0"
 ^0   ^1    ^2    ^3
```

where the carets specify where `argv` entries point:

```
argv = {&caret0, &caret1, &caret2, &caret3, NULL};
```

The advantage to this approach is minimal allocator overhead (it can be allocated and freed as a single block, without wasting bytes on alignment or heap tracking data). There is usually a limit on cumulative length of `argv` or the total number of arguments (OS/compiler dependent); it's large (on the most recent system I checked this on, the total length of the strings was limited to around 128KB), but you could hit it if you use a broad glob on a large tree of files.

The main hitch is the argument length limits, and the fact that all of the data is parsed/loaded at once, where `fgets` can use less memory by processing a line at a time, reusing a single (smaller) buffer. But if the length limits aren't a major issue, you could always use `xargs` to convert what would have been lines of input to `stdin` into sequential arguments to your program. It's a little odd, but not impossible.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> However why would argv[] need to be a pointer instead of also a variable in and of itself?

For the same reason you use a pointer to any other function: to avoid copying the arguments, or to pass an array. `argv` needs both. By passing `argv` in as `char *argv[]` only one pointer has to be copied rather than a potentially large amount of memory. Since `argv` is an array of arrays (strings are really pointers to byte arrays) there is no other way to pass it in (someone might be able to come up with a convoluted struct).

Since this happens *every time a program is run* it's very important. It was even more important back in the 70s and 80s when C and Unix were being developed and computers had very little memory and CPU.

> Where is the memory provisioned for the arguments, is there a limit?

Memory for arguments is usually allocated by the operating system or shell. In a POSIX system your program is generally called by using one of the [`exec` family of functions which passes in `argv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp). The limit is imposed by the operating system. In POSIX you can find it from the [`ARG_MAX` constant in limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html).

> Are there potential 'catches' to using arguments for input instead of fgets?

As above, the total size of the arguments, including the program name, has a limit. On my Mac it's 262144 bytes or 256K. On [Windows 95 it can be as low as 1024 bytes](https://metacpan.org/source/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.24/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Win95.pm#L44) and [2048 bytes on Win32](https://metacpan.org/source/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.24/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Win32.pm#L584).  I've encountered limits [as low as 256 bytes in old VMS systems](https://metacpan.org/source/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.24/lib/ExtUtils/MM_VMS.pm#L2029) and [have had to maintain extensive code to work around these limits](https://metacpan.org/source/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.24/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm#L302) when generating Makefiles (which are basically a pile of shell commands).

`fgets`, on the other hand, is limited only by the maximum file size of your filesystem. If you read from STDIN there is no limit that I know of.

Comment: I've been trying to force myself to understand why I'm using dereferences and what they are actually doing. Thanks for your input, it really helps.

Comment: @ZachGates Great! Here's one way to think about it. Memory is like a storage place where you can instantly go to any unit. A pointer is like a post-it note that says "Storage Unit 1234". You can go there instantly and rummage around. Passing by value is like saying "duplicate all the stuff in storage unit 1234, and move it to my storage unit" which takes time and eats up space. The down side of pointers is if you make any changes to storage unit 1234 then it affects everyone using storage unit 1234. This is, of course, very simplified.